# Best replacement of .deep method in Scala 2.13

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections

Since .deep method is been removed since Scala 2.13
What would be the best way to compare two Arrays that would work same as .deep?
Example:(Before Scala 2.13, it would work as follows)

```
 scala> Array(Array(1),2).deep == Array(Array(1),2).deep
 res3: Boolean = true
```

One preferred solution is to use sameElements method, but this method does not work if the Array is nested. Example:

```
scala> Array(Array(1),2) sameElements Array(Array(1),2)
res0: Boolean = false
```

Note: I'm using Scala 2.13.3

Comment: Do not use `Array`?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason - 1) use `List` or `Vector` or any other immutable collection, 2) don't create things that resolves something to `Any` (ADT?). Then you have equality for free.

Comment: I need a solution using Arrays only.

Comment: You would need to implement your own comparison function using `while` loops and `isInstanceOf` checks. - The only reason for using **Arrays** is raw performance, `deep` was pretty slow so it didn't make sense. Why do you need **Arrays**? Also, since they are nested they are all `Array[Any]` which is pretty useless and non-idiomatic. - If you go against the language, the language will go against you. It would be better to fix your design, that way this problem would solve by itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in equality and you're dealing with native arrays you can use `java.util.Arrays.deepEquals`, which is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-).

Quoting the documentation:

> Returns `true` if the two specified arrays are *deeply equal* to one
> another. Unlike the `equals(Object[],Object[])` method, this method is
> appropriate for use with nested arrays of arbitrary depth.
>
> Two array references are considered deeply equal if both are `null`, or
> if they refer to arrays that contain the same number of elements and
> all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are deeply
> equal.
>
> Two possibly null elements `e1` and `e2` are deeply equal if any of the
> following conditions hold:
>
> - `e1` and `e2` are both arrays of object reference types, and `Arrays.deepEquals(e1, e2)` would return true
> - `e1` and `e2` are arrays of the same primitive type, and the appropriate overloading of `Arrays.equals(e1, e2)` would return `true`.
> - `e1 == e2`
> - `e1.equals(e2)` would return `true`.
>
> Note that this definition permits `null` elements at any depth.
>
> If either of the specified arrays contain themselves as elements
> either directly or indirectly through one or more levels of arrays,
> the behavior of this method is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

@stefanobaghino solution is good.

But if you don't have `Array[Object]` but other type like e.g. `Array[Byte]`, it could be better [Objects.deepEquals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-), that allows any Array type to be used.